# use php to format page into a table

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I am trying to use the following code to sort a page into a format of within a table, I need to be able to extract the h4, span and non span into Name, Price, Item of a table

```
<?php
$c = file_get_contents('http://www.bunnings.com.au/products_category_plumbing-supplies_1637.aspx'); 
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($c);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$div = $xpath->query('//div[@class="details"]');
$div = $div->item(0);
echo $dom->saveXML($div);
?>
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: how do i extract it out further, so that i get the h4, span and non span into a table

Comment: Edit your question to include that, and add a clear example of what you currently get along with an example of what you want. Write a good question and you'll get a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple example will put the name, price and item number into a table:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$div = $xpath->query('//div[@class="details"]');

echo '<table>';

foreach($div as $details)
{
    $name = $details->getElementsByTagName('h4')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $price = $details->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('span')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $itemNumber = $details->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0)->childNodes->item(2)->nodeValue;

    $html = '<tr>';
    $html .= '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($name) . '</td>';
    $html .= '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($price) . '</td>';
    $html .= '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($itemNumber) . '</td>';
    $html .= '</tr>';

    echo $html;
}

echo '</table>';
```